# Ping not working in IBSS (ad-hoc) network on Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have five Raspberry Pis, each is equipped with an TP-LINK TL-WN722N (ath9k_hal). Together they form an Ad-hoc network. I setup arp tables on all the Pis over a ssh connection from my laptop. If I do not set the arp tables the Pis cannot ping each other.

My problem: I can ping for a few minutes, but then suddenly they won't ping. At some random time ping starts working again to some, but it stops working again.

How can I make ping working all the time?

**EDIT:**
I added my laptop to the network, using an Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG. My laptop can always ping the Pis, and after pinging all the Pis the Pis can ping each other.

Comment: Raspi restarted, used too much cpu to ping, lost network connection. Could be anything. Try collecting logs and post them here.

Comment: @Minix I'm not sure which log to look for. Also, I updated the question.